# Finding the lowest value in a Dataframe Row in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to find out the lowest value from a [row] in a DataFrame. How can I do that? My dataset is something like this:

```
aaaa |-32566.335700000003|         27668.7725|         20183.4786|
bbbb | -3.924099999999997|  5.802000000000006|  4.988000000000004|
cccc |  951546.8948000005| -686025.1569999934| -62493.96830000022|
xxxx |-26563.328700000005| 52490.610100000005|          -5555.277|
```

Research: What I am trying to do is transpose the above and then doing the sort and select on the above rows as columns. Please suggest any alternative way, either using the Spark Dataset functions already out there.

The above is just a sample dataset the actual number of columns are much more than this to get the lowest value in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting all the numeric columns in a row as a list, and then finding the minimum value in this list:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a",1.0,2.0,3.0),("b",-1.0,-2.0,-3.0),("c",-1.0,0.0,1.0))).toDF("id","v1","v2","v3")
df.show

val numericCols = List("v1", "v2", "v3") // you can get these from the df.schema if you need generic approach

val dfMin = df.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("id"), numericCols.map(column => r.getAs[Double](column)).min)).toDF("id", "minValue")
dfMin.show
```